# I can't find the option to exclude constraints when using SQL Server Management Studio script generation

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a situation where we are creating data interfaces for external customers.

Our managers push out sets of data to an external database from a secure internal database. The external database needs to have the exact table structure as the internal database, but it does not need any of the relational constraints since the data is being managed by an internal copy.

I have tried using generate script, I can't seem to find the right 'Advanced Options' that will generate the script so that it won't use the incremental IDENTITY or CONSTRAINT definitions when the script is generated. The default seems to always include them.

I assume I am just not selecting the right options.

Edit:
Here is the option selection and an example of the result. 
I could do a Find and then Replace All for the 'IDENTITY', but the 'CONSTRAINT' items seem a bit more cumbersome.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set:

```
Advanced Scripting Options -> Table/view options -> Script Foreign Key -> False
```

[image]

Comment: I just a added a screenshot of my config. I have the Foreign Keys already set false, but I still get other constraint references.